Opening an Access report using VB.NET
I'm using this code that I found on vb.net Macorotti, which I've adapted to run Visual Studio 2019. It works when printing, but when I ask it to preview the AcWindowMode.acWindowNormal report, it sends it to the printer too. Help me find a solution.
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access

Public Class Frm_AccessRelatorio
    Private Sub Frm_AccessRelatorio_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cboRelatorios.SelectedIndex = 0
        BtnFechar.Focus()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnExecutar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExecutar.Click

        If cboRelatorios.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um relatório", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Return
        End If
        Try
            Dim MSA As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application
            MSA.Application.Visible = False

            MSA.OpenCurrentDatabase(strPath & "\Teste.accdb", False)

            If rdbVisualizar.Checked Then
                MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport(cboRelatorios.Text, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcWindowMode.acWindowNormal)
                'maximiza a janela
                MSA.Application.DoCmd.Maximize()

            Else
                MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport(cboRelatorios.Text, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewNormal)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Erro : " & ex.Message, "Erro ao acessar o objeto", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

I have no idea how to solve it.

It sends to the printer, since that's what "normal" means in VBA, and hence it means the same thing in vb.net.
Next up, if you trying to preview the report, then you have to make Access visible, and you have visible = False, which of course will defeat your whole goal here to display the report in place of printing the report.
So, this code works for me:
    Dim MSA As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application

    MSA.Application.Visible = True

    MSA.OpenCurrentDatabase("c:\test\test444.accdb", False)


    MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport("rptHotelsA",
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewPreview)

Note the use of "preview" in place of "Normal", since as noted, normal = send directly to printer.
On the other hand, it not at all clear why you want to launch a copy of Access in VB, and then launch a report, since such a process is far better served by doing this in Access without introduction of VB code.
However, regardless of your goals here, you need to open the report in "preview" mode, not "normal", and to see the report, you have to set the Access application object with Visible = true.
Edit: Hiding most of the Access interface.
In the comments, the question was how to hide the Access interface.
As I pointed out, you can hide most, if not all of the Access UI, and only show the report.
The settings in Access are:
Use tabbed interface, turn off tabs.
Hence, file->options->Current Database->Document windows options.
So, set tabbed interface (not overlapping windows), and turn off display of tabs.
Hence this:

Then under navigation, turn off display of navigation pane.
Hence this:

As noted, at this point, then the only UI will be the report, and the report ribbon. I often like and want the report ribbon, since it allows the user to send/save the report to a PDF, or print the report.
So, now the result of above is a window with a report, and only the report and the report ribbon displays. And if you use acReportView, then the report ribbon does not even display.
And if you re-size the Access window, the report will always re-size to the given window size you have. The result is this:

As noted, you could I suppose turn off the ribbon.
Hence, with this vb.net code:
    Dim MSA As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application

    MSA.Application.Visible = True

    MSA.OpenCurrentDatabase("c:\test\test444.accdb", False)

    MSA.Application.DoCmd.ShowToolbar("Ribbon", 2)

    MSA.Application.DoCmd.OpenReport("rptHotelsA",
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewReport)

And now the result is just a window with the report.
Hence:

So, with just a few simple settings, you can with ease hide most of the Access UI.

Albert D. Kallal, thank you very much for your help, I thought it would be possible to open the report without making Access visible.

No, but you can use tabbed interface,  turn off tabs, and you only see the ribbon and the report,  and nothing else (turn off the nav pane also). I suppose you could also turn off ribbon,  but that would make printing difficult if required.  So you can have just the report show with suggested settings

How can I do that, that would be great.
I tried to use MSA.Application.CommandBars but I can't manipulate the panels

See my edit, it is really just a few easy settings, and the result is most if not all of the Access UI will be hidden. And you can even re-size that "report", and while that window will re-size, you not see much of, if any of the Access UI.

Albert D. Kallal, thank you very much.
